# Scale up an image!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Your task is to write a program/function to scale up an image (list of strings) by a factor of `n`.

## Specs

- You will receive two inputs: an image, and a positive integer.
- The image will only contain ASCII printable characters (U+0020-U+007F).

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes wins.

## Testcases

#### Testcase 1

```
abc
xyz

2

aabbcc
aabbcc
xxyyzz
xxyyzz
```

#### Testcase 2

```
|_|

3

|||___|||
|||___|||
|||___|||
```

Comment: Can you please try to use the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) next time? I see that you have already gotten negative votes on two previous questions today, and now this one has been marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 23 bytes

```
╗'
@s`╜;)*(Zk♂ΣiΣn`M'
j
```

Takes the string input (with newlines represented as `\n`s to make multi-line input work) as the first input and the integer as the second.

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4pWXJwpAc2DilZw7KSooWmvimYLOo2nOo25gTScKag&input=ImFiY1xueHl6Igoz)

Explanation (newlines replaced with `\n`):

```
╗'\n@s`╜;)*(Zk♂ΣiΣn`M'\nj
╗                          push n to reg0
 '\n@s                     split s on newlines
      `╜;)*(Zk♂ΣiΣn`M      for each line:
       ╜;)*(Z                make n copies and zip them
             k♂ΣiΣ           join the strings ("abc" -> ["abc", "abc"] -> "aabbcc" with n = 2)
                  n          make n copies of the result line
                     '\nj  join on newline
```

Comment: Actually, this is quite long... (Pyth may need not more than 10 bytes I reckon)

Comment: @KennyLau Actually doesn't do well with string manipulation. Its strength is math.

Comment: So, this looks like an old answer, but I don't think `\n` is actually part of CP437.